# jsoup exception

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I have for loop that looks like this:

```
//Pseudo code

subUrl = divs.get(n).select("a[href].eDL");

for (int o = 0; o<subUrl.size(); o++) {

    subUrlW = subUrl.get(o).select("a[href].eDL").attr("abs:href");
                                          
    httpget = new HttpGet(subUrlW);
    HttpResponse httpRes2 = httpclient1.execute(httpget, httpContext);
    html = EntityUtils.toString(httpRes2.getEntity());
    doc = Jsoup.parse(html, subUrlW);
    divs = doc.select("div#pTU");

    for (int p = 0; p < divs.size(); p++) {
                                              
        subUrl = divs.get(p).select("a[href].pd");
        for (int q = 0; q < subUrl.size(); q++) {  

             subUrlW = subUrl.get(q).select("a[href].pd").attr("abs:href"); 
                                         
        }
    }                                              
}
```

I see that subUrlW is null however if I execute this to debug, subUrlW is not null.

```
subUrl = divs.get(n).select("a[href].eDL");

for (int o = 0; o < subUrl.size(); o++) {
    subUrlW = subUrl.get(o).select("a[href].eDL").attr("abs:href");
    System.out.println("subUrlW"+subUrlW);
}
```

When this loop executes, I get the following exception,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:717)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:358)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
```

It however points to his line,

```
HttpResponse httpRes2 = httpclient1.execute(httpget, httpContext);
```

any inputs much appreciated.

Comment: I'd wager that `subUrlW` is `null`. Use a debugger to find out.

Comment: You are right, i have added another set of code above which shows subUrlW is not null, but when I execute the 1st set of code it comes as null.

Answer (score 0):

```
subUrl = divs.get(n).select("a[href].eDL");

Document doc = null;

for (int o = 0; o < subUrl.size(); o++) 
{    
    doc = JSoup.connect(subUrl[o].toString());
    subUrlW = doc.select("a[href].eDL").attr("abs:href");
    System.out.println("subUrlW"+subUrlW);
    doc = null;    
}
```